# Unable to connect via dash_mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, plotly-dash

As an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68418331/mqtt-function-display-output-in-dash) question and based on the answers, I am using `websockets` to connect to MQTT broker using `dash_mqtt` taking [this app script](https://github.com/aegis1980/dash-mqtt) as a reference. But I am not able to send or receive data with the configuration in the below `app.py`.

```
import dash_mqtt
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import flask
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt



TEST_SERVER = '172.17.0.2'
TEST_SERVER_PORT = 1883
TEST_SERVER_PATH = 'mqtt'
MESSAGE_OUT_TOPIC = 'testtopic'
MESSAGE_IN_TOPIC = 'testtopic'

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True



app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_mqtt.DashMqtt(
        id='mqtt',
        broker_url=TEST_SERVER,
        broker_port = TEST_SERVER_PORT,
        broker_path = TEST_SERVER_PATH,
        topics=[MESSAGE_IN_TOPIC]
    ),
    html.H1('MQTT echo'),
    html.P('MQTT echo server to ' + TEST_SERVER + ' on port ' + str(TEST_SERVER_PORT)),
    dcc.Input(
        id='message_to_send',
        placeholder='message to send',
        debounce = True),
    html.Button('Send',id='send'),
    html.Div(id='return_message')
])


@app.callback(
        Output('mqtt', 'message'),
        Input('send', 'n_clicks'),
        State('message_to_send', 'value')
    )
def display_output(n_clicks, message_payload):
    if n_clicks:
        return {
            'topic': MESSAGE_OUT_TOPIC,
            'payload' : message_payload
        }
    return dash.no_update

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',port=8050,debug=True)
```

In brief,

1. I am trying to connect to `eclipse mqtt` broker which is running
   in a docker container associated with the IP address
   `172.17.0.2` listening to the port `1883`.
2. Dash app is running in another docker container with the port `8050`.

All the basic configuration to the mosquitto.config file is done so that it listens and responds to external communications. Also, this app runs successfully without errors in the log but cannot communicate with the MQTT broker.

What configuration changes should I have to make to connect to the broker?

Thank you

Edit: The browser console says`WebSocket connection to 'ws://172.17.0.2:1883/mqtt' failed:`

`mosquitto.conf`

```
# Config file for mosquitto

# =================================================================
# Listeners
# =================================================================

# listener port-number [ip address/host name/unix socket path]
listener 1883

# =================================================================
# Persistence
# =================================================================

persistence True

# =================================================================
# Security
# =================================================================

# Defaults to false, unless there are no listeners defined in the configuration
# file, in which case it is set to true, but connections are only allowed from
# the local machine.
allow_anonymous True
```

Comment: Edit the question to show your mosquitto.conf, because normally it will not responds to Websocket connections on port 1883. Also have you looked at the browser console to see what errors are present?

Comment: @hardillb, I am not able to add mosquitto.conf because of limited body length in the question, but the changes I have made are, `listener 1883`,`persistence true` and `allow_anonymous true`. Apart from these I have not made any changes. Also, Images for the browser and docker console are added to the question. Basically there are no errors in the console.

Comment: You need to add a second listener on a different port with the protocol set to websockets.

Comment: Also do NOT add images of text, always post the text and format it. You can edit out all of the comments from the mosquitto.conf to make it fit.

Comment: The image of the browser is meaningless, I asked about the browsers console, which is normally accessed by hitting F12

Comment: @hardillb, You are right and I am sorry, I have edited the question as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments,

You can not use the same port for Native MQTT over TCP and MQTT over Websockets, so you will need to add a second listener to the `mosquitto.conf`

e.g

```
listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

And change the port in your app to be `1884`